# Cannot open include file: 'initializer_list'

Tags: c++, visual-c++, boost, c++11, initializer-list

I want to compile The Forgotten Server (Tibia OTServer) on Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 (MSVC).
But at the file: unordered_set.hpp I have this:

```
#if !defined(BOOST_NO_0X_HDR_INITIALIZER_LIST)
#include <initializer_list>
#endif
```

and is giving me the errors:

> boost/unordered/unordered_set.hpp(27): fatal error C1083: Cannot open
>   include file: 'initializer_list': No such file or directory
>   (..\spells.cpp)
>
> boost/unordered/unordered_set.hpp(27): fatal error C1083: Cannot open
>   include file: 'initializer_list': No such file or directory
>   (..\talkaction.cpp)

What can I do?

---

By defining BOOST_NO_0X_HDR_INITIALIZER_LIST now I have the following error:

```
..\scriptmanager.cpp(147): error C2039: 'string' : is not a member of 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>'
          with
          [
              _Elem=char,
              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
              _Alloc=std::allocator<char>
          ]
```

at:

```
std::string s = BOOST_DIR_ITER_FILENAME(it);
```

Comment: Define `BOOST_NO_0X_HDR_INITIALIZER_LIST` before including anything (VC++ does not support `std::initializer_list`).

Comment: The November CTP does support it, by the way.

Comment: Install the [November CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35515).

Comment: well, I have just installed November CTP as Jerry and Chris said, but still i get those errors, what do I do?

Comment: I also defined BOOST_NO_0X_HDR_INITIALIZER_LIST as ildjarn said, but is that the correct way to fix the problem?

Comment: It looks like "The Forgotten Server" has modified things to assume a non MSVC++ compiler -- `boost::config` is supposed to define that macro as appropriate for your compiler.

Comment: Are you still getting errors about being unable to find `<initializer_list>`, or something else? If you've installed it properly, that header should be found (I've used it).

Comment: Please try building with the beta release of boost 1.53.0. There have been some updates to the Boost.config specifically for MSVC 2012.  You can get the beta at http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_53_0.html